# A name for a weak topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, duality

Let $V$ be a real vector space and let $V'$ be the algebraic dual of $V$, i.e. the space of all the linear functionals $V\to\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists the weakest topology $\tau$ which makes all the elements of $V'$ continuous, and $\tau$ is locally convex and Hausdorff. For example, if the dimension on $V$ is finite, then $\tau$ is the usual Euclidean topology.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a commonly used name for $\tau$?
2. Let $\tau'$ be the maximal locally convex topology on $V$, i.e. the weakest topology that makes all the seminorms on $V$ continuous. Of course $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$, but $\tau'$ and $\tau$ could coincide in some cases (for example, for finite dimensional spaces). What is the exact relationship between $\tau$ and $\tau'$?

Comment: Is $V$ already a topological vector space?

Comment: No, it isn't. The topology tau only depends on the underlying linear structure of V.

Comment: Just a wee addendum to the answer below.  The topology $\tau'$ is the Mackey topology on $V$, i.e., the finest locally convex topology for the duality $(V,V')$, aka the topology of uniform convergence on the weakly (i.e., $\sigma(V',V)$) compact subsets of $V'$.  Thus, in a certain sense, they are as far apart as possible---the finest and the weakest locally convex topologies for this duality.

Answer (score 6):

I got into trouble in following prof. Johnson's suggestion, and now I am quite convinced that the topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$ coincide only when $V$ is finite-dimensional.

In fact, let $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis for $V$, and let us consider the seminorm

$p(\sum_{i\in I} v_i x_i)=\sum_{i\in I} |v_i|$

(this seminorm is well-defined since every element in $V$ admits a unique representation as a finite linear combination of elements of the basis). Then the set $U=p^{-1}(-1,1)$ is open in $\tau'$, and does not contain any nontrivial linear subspace of $V$.

On the other hand, since $\tau$ is the weak topology with respect to a family of linear functionals (in fact, with respect to all the linear functionals), every $\tau$-neighbourhood of $0\in V$ must contain a finite-codimensional linear subspace of $V$. Therefore, if the dimension of $V$ is not finite, then the set $U$ introduced above is open with respect to $\tau'$, and not open with respect to $\tau$.

Answer (score 3):

The two topologies are the same.  See e.g. Problem 20G in Kelley-Namioka "Linear Topological Spaces".

Comment: BTW, they call the topology the "strongest locally convex topology on $V$".

Comment: Bill, are you sure? this seems strange.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I did not think about the problem but just gave the reference and misquoted it.  In K-L problem 20G, the statement is that all admissible topologies on `$V^*$` (rather than on $V$ itself) are the same, which is pretty clear because `$V^*$` is a product of copies of the scalar field. Roberto'a answer is the correct one.